# Calling Rekognition using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-rekognition

I have the AWS CLI installed on Windows and am using the Windows command prompt.

I am trying to use Rekognition but I cannot seem to get any commands working. The closest I have gotten is with:

```
aws rekognition detect-faces --image S3Object=\{Bucket=innovation-bucket,Name=image.jpg,Version=1\} --attributes "ALL" --region us-east-1
```

This results in:

> Error parsing parameter '--image': Expected: ',', received: '}' for input: S3Object={Bucket=innovation-bucket,Name=image.jpg,Version=1}

Why is it expecting a comma?

**EDIT:**

When I try the format from the documentation I also get errors:

```
aws rekognition detect-faces --image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"innovation-bucket","Name":"image.jpg"}}' --attributes "ALL" --region us-east-1
```

> Error parsing parameter '--image': Expected: '=', received ''' for input: '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"innovation-bucket","Name":"image.jpg‌​"}}'

Comment: These examples could help, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example3.html#example3-searchingfaces-cli

Comment: @Nambari I have tried everything seen in the documentation and it's just caused many errors

Comment: Did you follow the proper single quotes & double quotes?

Comment: When I try `aws rekognition detect-faces --image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"innovation-bucket","Name":"image.jpg"}}' --attributes "ALL" --region us-east-1` I get `Error parsing parameter '--image': Expected: '=', received ''' for input: '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"innovation-bucket","Name":"image.jpg"}}'`

Comment: Which box AWS CLI client is on Windows (or) Mac (or) Linux etc.,?

Comment: @Nambari `aws-cli/1.11.80 Python/3.3.5 Windows/7 botocore/1.5.43`

Comment: Could you try the solution described here, the one 'windows cmd you can change single quotes (') to double quotes etc.,, 
https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-dynamodb/discussion/-KUX8EQjmN7F2pNKvoWW/?answer=-KXh-a7NIDibsq4dbAsR

Comment: @Nambari Changing the single quotes to double quotes and the double quotes to escaped quotes worked!

Comment: Glad it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Your AWS CLI should be something like below, refer [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example3.html#example3-searchingfaces-cli):

```
aws rekognition search-faces-by-image \
--image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"bucket-name","Name":"Example.jpg"}}' \
--collection-id "collection-id" \
--region us-east-1 \
--profile adminuser
```

2) If your AWS CLI installed on windows box, make sure you change **"the single quotes to double quotes and the double quotes to escaped quotes"**

Comment: For clarity - 
' becomes " while
" becomes /"

Comment: Double Quotes " becomes \"    NOT /"   See this page under "Using Quotation Marks with Strings" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

```
aws rekognition search-faces-by-image \
--image "{\"S3Object\":{\"Bucket\":\"bucket-name\",\"Name\":\"Example.jpg\"}}' \
--collection-id "collection-id" \
--region us-east-1 \
--profile adminuser
```

every double quote should have escape character with \ don't miss any thing